# mitmproxy redirect request to localhost and set Host header

Tags: python, curl, reverse-proxy, mitmproxy

I'm running a http server locally on port `8181`. I have my `mitmproxy` configured on my devices and now I need to forward requests from a specific domain to my local server instance. So I'm using the request redirect example script described [here](https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/blob/master/examples/redirect_requests.py):

```
def request(flow):
    # pretty_host takes the "Host" header of the request into account,
    # which is useful in transparent mode where we usually only have the IP
    # otherwise.

    # Method 2: Redirect the request to a different server
    if flow.request.pretty_host.endswith("mydomain.com"):
        flow.request.headers["Host"] = flow.request.headers
        flow.request.host = "localhost"
        flow.request.port = 8181
        flow.request.scheme = 'http'
```

This works, but I need to set the `Host` header to the original request host so I followed the add header example described [here](https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/blob/master/examples/add_header.py) doing like

```
flow.request.headers["Host"] = flow.request.headers
```

but when in `mitmproxy` I cannot see this header set in the request, and I don't get it on the `localhost` server logs.

So what I want to do it the same as `cURL`

```
curl -b c -c c "http://localhost:8181/something" -H "Host: mydomain.com"
```

in order to have at least the needed request headers like

```
*   Trying ::1...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8181 (#0)
> GET /something HTTP/1.1
> Host:mydomain.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:    flow.request.headers["Host"] = ["mydomain.com"]
refer: https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/blob/v0.9.2/examples/redirect_requests.py